# No lower heating element

Tags: oven

I noticed that my GE oven does not have a lower heating element, after more than 5 years of use.   Is that normal or a defect?

Comment: Welcome Jerry, while your question seems to be good. Its a little more detail. Five years seems a bit short for an element to wear out. However, if you bought it or received it used, it may be more normal. Also, please feel free to check out the tour and help centre to better assist you in asking better questions for this site. And as always welcome to Seasoned Advice.

Comment: What does it say in the instructions, or on the dial on the front... or what model is it...

Answer (score 1):

If it's like my GE oven, the lower element is actually underneath the bottom surface of the interior of the oven; it's not exposed like the broiler coil is on top. While nice, I suppose, it does add a couple minutes to preheating time.

Check your owner's manual to see if this is the case in your oven.